# How to get response data from the server in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, hapi.js

This is my scenario. A server in nodejs handles the authentication procedure while in the frontend we have angularjs. when the user clicks on the button, he signs in with Facebook then the server handles all the aspects of the authentication at the end redirect to the uri of the angularjs application. We have in the server something like that

```
module.exports = function(request, reply) {

  if (request.auth.isAuthenticated) {

    var profile = request.auth.credentials.profile.raw;

    // set to cookie
    request.auth.session.set(profile);

    // Perform any account lookup or registration, setup local session,
    // and redirect to the application. The third-party credentials are
    // stored in request.auth.credentials. Any query parameters from
    // the initial request are passed back via request.auth.credentials.query

    // here we should redirect the app flow somewhere
    return reply({ profile: profile.id }).redirect('http://localhost:8080/app');
  }

  return reply('Unauthorized').code(401);
};
```

My issue is that I don't know how to retrieve profile object in angularjs. I mean I know that exist `$http` provider but in the following case the request doesn't start from angularjs. summering the flow the server reply with SPA if the user sign is successfully

---

```
$http.get('/app')
  .success(function(data){
     console.log(data);
   });
```

Comment: Once the SPA is loaded, you must still use `$http` for fetching the profile data.

Comment: ok but which should be the uri to pass?

Comment: I mean I always intended that $http provider start the call but in this case the flow is different. the server serve the SPA

Comment: should maybe I use /app ?

Comment: In both cases, the SPA is served from server. So the flow doesn't change. You must redirect to the app uri /app

Comment: something is not clear for me and it is not working. I redirect the server to the uri of the angularjs app. in that uri there is the an $http provider someting like that above

Comment: /app is the url corresponding to an ui-router state

Comment: @mohamedrias when I call $http in the SPA it call the server then the server is called twice. are you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes, i understood. Before that, where the login button is present? is it part of the angular app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send it as an URL Parameter using the $routeProvider

your config should look like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/login/:profileId', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
  }]);
```

your controller:

```
app.controller("loginCtrl",function($routeParams,$scope){
   $scope.profileId = $routeParams.profileId;
   //YOU CAN REDIRECT HERE TO ANOTHER VIEW AFTER
})
```

Back-end

```
module.exports = function(request, reply) {

  if (request.auth.isAuthenticated) {

    var profile = request.auth.credentials.profile.raw;

    // set to cookie
    request.auth.session.set(profile);

    // Perform any account lookup or registration, setup local session,
    // and redirect to the application. The third-party credentials are
    // stored in request.auth.credentials. Any query parameters from
    // the initial request are passed back via request.auth.credentials.query

    // here we should redirect the app flow somewhere
    return reply({ profile: profile.id
    // use # for html5 mode 
  }).redirect('http://localhost:8080/app/#/login/'+profile.id);
  }

  return reply('Unauthorized').code(401);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. it was easier than I ever expected